# Observable fromIterable just return one item

Tags: android, observable, rx-java, iterable

My observable.fromIterable is just returning 1 time.

I am trying to return a list of elements like Observable objects. For that I am using "fromIterable". topMoviesRated.getResults() is returning 20 objects, doOnNext is being callin 20 times but the method getResultFromNetwork is just returning the first element.

Presenter:

```
public void loadData(boolean error) {
    subscription = model.result(error)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<MyFilm>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(MyFilm object) {
            if(view!=null){
                view.updateData(object);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(view!=null){
                view.showSnackbar("Error...");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            if(view!=null){
                view.showSnackbar("Finished...");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Model:

```
public Observable<MyFilm> result(boolean error) {
    if (error)
        repository.setPagination(1);
    else
        repository.setPagination(++pagination);

    return Observable.zip(repository.getResultFromNetwork(), detailResult(),  new BiFunction<Result, Details, MyFilm>() {
                @Override
                public MyFilm apply(Result result, Details details) {
                    return new MyFilm(result.getOriginalName(), result.getId().toString(), details);
                }
            });
}

public Observable<Details> detailResult() {
    return Observable.zip(repository.getDetailsData(), repository.getCountryData(), new BiFunction<TVDetails, String, Details>() {
        @Override
        public Details apply(TVDetails tvDetails, String country) {
            return new Details(tvDetails, country);
        }
    });
}
```

Repository:

```
public Observable<Result> getResultFromNetwork() {
    Observable<TopMoviesRated> topMoviesRatedObservable = moviesApiService.getTopMovies("es_ES", pagination);
    return topMoviesRatedObservable.concatMap(new Function<TopMoviesRated, Observable<Result>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Result> apply(TopMoviesRated topMoviesRated) {
            return Observable.fromIterable(topMoviesRated.getResults());
        }
    }).doOnNext(new Consumer<Result>() { 
        @Override
        public void accept(Result result) {
            Log.d("OnNext -->", result.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that issue in `getResultFromNetwork()`? What does `detailResult()` return? Check out [how zip operator works](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html)

Comment: I edit it.  detailResult is getting the film details, it is another call to Api, but It still not working If I ignore this call

Comment: I add my presenter too

Comment: You have some contradictions in your question. You say that `doOnNext()` been called 20 times. This means that `getResultFromNetwork()` works fine. As I've already told, you need to understand how zip operator works. Reason of your issue is that you have List of 20 items and only one Detail item. Zip operator requires two lists with same size. So you need list of details with same size.

Comment: I understand it, I add detailResult() to my code. I have another example where this code is working, the diference between this code and the other one is, in this one I am calling it from a fragment in the other one I am calling it from an Activity

Answer (score 1):

Check out this image. The first list has 5 items and second only 4. As you see, result of zip operator contains only 4 items.[image: zip operator]

Answer (score 0):

Yamko is right, `zip` is not what you need. Try to use `Observable.combineLatest` instead of it

Comment: I am going to try it